# How to cycling Arrays to display all the data of all the rows of a table?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, foreach, iteration

I created an HTML page where the user is asked to fill a search form and click on the button "*Search*" in order to display results.

When the "*Search*" button is clicked, if the form field is not empty some data will be displayed after 2 seconds (I used the Javascript `setTimeout()` method to achieve that).

The data to display consist of several names, surnames, and addresses, and they do correspond to the three `<td>` of the three `<tr>` of the table named "Name", "Surname" and "Address".

In the js file, I created a new variable called `myArray`:

```
var myArray = [
  //first row
    [
      ["Mary", "Otto", "1204 Stoney Ridge"],
      ["Paula", "Red", "445 Mount Eden Road"],
      ["Jack", "Twist", "21 Greens Road RD 2"]
    ],

  //second row
    [
      ["Oliver", "Howick", "32 Wilson Street"],
      ["Jean", "Bros", "address 5"],
      ["Antoine", "Lavoisier", "address 6"]
    ],
  //third row
    [
      ["Benny", "Fair", "address 7"],
      ["Corinne", "Robespierre", "address 8"],
      ["Michael", "Mury", "address 9"]
    ]
  ];
```

I want to cycle `myArray` in order to display all the series of "*name*, *surname*, *address*" without having to type them all. I'm trying to use the Javascript `for loop` method in order to do so:

```
    function validateNome(){
  console.log('function validateNome has been activated');
  if ($("#inlineFormInputNome").val()=="") {
      $("#errorLog").show();
  } else {      
    $("#errorLog").hide();   
    $("#cercaNome").prop("disabled", true);
    $("#tbody").empty();
    setTimeout(function (){
      //ID alert bootstrap      
      //$("#tbody").empty().append('<tr><th scope="row">1</th><td>Maria</td><td>Ottone</td><td>Viale della Resistenza 1, 53100 Siena (SI)</td></tr>');
      // aggiungi un'array e mostra i dati dell'array

      var myArray = [
      //first row
        [
          ["Mary", "Otto", "1204 Stoney Ridge"],
          ["Paula", "Red", "445 Mount Eden Road"],
          ["Jack", "Twist", "21 Greens Road RD 2"]
        ],

      //second row
        [
          ["Oliver", "Howick", "32 Wilson Street"],
          ["Jean", "Bros", "address 5"],
          ["Antoine", "Lavoisier", "Via Flogisto 1"]
        ],
      //third row
        [
          ["Benny", "Fair", "address 7"],
          ["Corinne", "Robespierre", "address 8"],
          ["Michael", "Mury", "address 9"]
        ]
      ];

        for(var i=0; i<myArray.length; i++) {
          $("#tbody").append  ('<tr><th scope="row"> </th><td> myArray [0][0][0]</td> <td>myArray [0][0][1]</td><td> myArray [0][0][2] </td></tr>');
      }
      $("#tabella").show();
      $("#cercaNome").prop("disabled", false);
    } , 2000);
  }
}
```

In other terms, what I did  is substituting the following line:

`$("#tbody").append('<tr><th scope="row">1</th><td>Mary</td><td>Otto</td><td>1204 Stoney Ridge</td></tr>');`

with the `for loop` function below:

```
for(var i=0; i<myArray.length; i++) {

      $("#tbody").append  (

    '<tr><th scope="row"> </th><td> myArray [0][0][0]</td> <td>myArray [0][0][1]</td><td> myArray [0][0][2] </td></tr>') ;
  }
```

where `myArray[0][0][0]` do correspond to *"Mary"* , `myArray[0][0][1]` do correspond to *"Otto"* and `myArray[0][0][2]` do correspond to *"1204 Stoney Ridge"*.

How to cycling Arrays to display all the 27 data `<td>` of the three different rows `<tr>` of a table when a button is being clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment you're iterating over myArray using the local variable **i**. You need to use it to reference a row from your array.

```
myArray[i][0]
```

Each row holds three additional arrays

```
myArray[i][0] myArray[i][1] myArray[i][2]
```

These can be accessed using another nested for loop like

```
for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < myArray[0][0].length; j++) {
    console.log(myArray[i][j]);
  }
}
```

To ultimately construct a valid tr element you need to access myArray's elements. At the moment you put it directly inside the string as part of the string.
e.g. the correct way `myString="the value "+myArray[0]+" the rest of my string"`

```
for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < myArray[0][0].length; j++) {
    $("#tbody").append("<tr><th scope='row'> </th><td>" + myArray[i][i][0] + "</td> <td>" + myArray[i][j][1] + "</td><td>" + myArray[i][i][2] + "</td></tr>");
  }
}
```